# JSP charts and graphs

Tags: java, jsp

I am having my own query which is:

select Name, count(requests)
from cap
group by name

So, how can I show that query as a graph in my jsp?

Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`JFreeChart`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) has some nice [`ChartUtilities`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartUtilities.html) that make it easy to stream a chart from a servlet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Java based APIs for chart generation like JFreeChart is that they have run on your server side. Which adds more load to the server.

I would suggest [**Google Charts API**](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery). This API provides a variety of charts with more and more visualisation and animations yet to come.
And most of all, All the hard work of generating complex charts are done at the client side.